# Changing background color of view depending on if statement

Tags: android, view

My question is about trying to change the background color of a view in Android studio in multiple places in a code.

I'm working on a booking system, and trying to change the color of a view based on if too many of a single ressource is booked.
The idea is to call a function called "tooManyItems()" to check this. and change the color accordingly, along with some other changes (but these work in the code below)

I'm working in API 20, to ensure functionality on more devices.

for understanding:

- input is an ArrayList with the custom class Ressource. this class has an int
  variable called group. we check this, because if group == 1, the view has no 
  edit text window

**The main problem:**

I cannot get anything setBackgroundColor to work on either the main, or info, if it is in both if and else of the innermost loop in tooManyItems. simply put: it will change the color once. but not back and forth.
It is important to not that the two first lines of code in the loops always work. I can get the textview to change background, and the imgError to appear no problem.

I declare my views like so:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
           nRessourcer.add((LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.valgt_ressource, null));
           editText_Amount.add((EditText) nRessourcer.get(i).findViewById(R.id.editText_Antal));
           imgError.add((ImageView) nRessourcer.get(i).findViewById(R.id.imgError));
           imgDelete.add((ImageView) nRessourcer.get(i).findViewById(R.id.imgDelete));
           textView_Ressource.add((TextView) nRessourcer.get(i).findViewById(R.id.textView_Ressource));
    }
```

info is declared when the view is clicked, and we call the function expand(), like so:

```
    public void expand() {
        if (isExpanded) {
//main.setBackgroundColor(colorItemAvailable);
            textView_header.setTextColor(colorWhite);
            textView_subheader.setTextColor(colorWhite);
            textView_pakkeTotal.setTextColor(colorWhite);
            expander.removeView(info);
            if (isBooked) expander.addView(reserveret);

            isExpanded = false;
        } else {
//                main.setBackgroundColor(test);
            textView_header.setTextColor(colorBlack);
            textView_subheader.setTextColor(colorBlack);
            textView_pakkeTotal.setTextColor(colorBlack);
            expander.addView(info);

            if (isBooked) expander.removeView(reserveret);
            isExpanded = true;
        }
}
```

after this I call the tooManyItems function.

```
public void tooManyItems() {

    for (int i = 0; i < nRessourcer.size(); i++) {
        editText_Amount.get(i).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nRessourcer.size(); i++) {
                    if (input.get(i).getGroup() == 2) {
                        if (!editText_Amount.get(i).getText().toString().matches("")) {
                            if (input.get(i).getAvaliable() < Integer.parseInt(editText_Amount.get(i).getText().toString())) {
                                imgError.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                main.setBackgroundColor(colorYellow);
                                infoMain.setBackgroundColor(colorYellow);
                                buttonReserver.setBackgroundColor(colorItemUnavailable); 
                                buttonReserver.setEnabled(false);  


                            } else {
                                if (input.get(i).getLedige() >= Integer.parseInt(editText_Antal.get(i).getText().toString())) {imgError.get(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                    editText_Amount.get(i).setBackgroundColor(colorGrey);
                                    main.setBackgroundColor(colorItemSelected);
                                    infoMain.setBackgroundColor(colorItemSelected);
                                    buttonReserver.setBackgroundColor(colorBlue);
                                    buttonReserver.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Please let me know if you want additional code. I saw no need in providing the entire class, because everything else works, and it is only the interplay here that is causing problems. Expand also worked on it's own, before tooManyItems was added.

I hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, by trying to rewrite it from scratch!

at the start of toManyItems, I removed the for loop, and gave it a final input, that the inner functions can use so that the start looks like this:

```
public void tooManyItems(final int i) {

    editText_Amount.get(i).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
and so on...
```

instead I call the function using a for loop, like so:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < nRessourcer.size(); i++) {
        tooManyItems(i);
    }
```

it now responds like it is supposed to.